# Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am ***not*** using Appengine.

I have a plain vanilla Django application running on a VM. I want to use Google Cloud Storage for serving my staticfiles, and also for uploading/serving my media files.

I have a bucket.

How do I link my Django application to my bucket? I've tried `django-storages`. That may work, but what do I have to do to prepare my bucket to be used by my django application? And what baseline configuration do I need in my Django settings?

Current settings:

```
# Google Cloud Storage
# http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/apache_libcloud.html
LIBCLOUD_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'type'  : 'libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE',
        'user'  : <I have no idea>,
        'key'   : <ditto above>,
        'bucket': <my bucket name>,
    }
}

DEFAULT_LIBCLOUD_PROVIDER = 'google'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.apache_libcloud.LibCloudStorage'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django-storages has a backend for Google Cloud Storage, but it is not documented, I realised looking in the repo. Got it working with this setup:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YourID'
GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YourKEY'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'YourBucket'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
```

To get YourKEY  and YourID  you should create `Interoperability` keys, in the settings tab.

Hope it helps and you don't have to learn it the hard way :)

Ah in case you haven't yet, the dependencies are:

```
pip install django-storages
pip install boto
```

Comment: I am getting GSResponseError: 401 Unauthorized any idea?

Comment: Why is `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'` required? It causes browsable API to fail loading css files.

Comment: I have a `client_secret` and a `client_key` generated from Oauth. Is that what I should be using for YourID and YourKEY?

Comment: django-storages nowadays has gcloud backend using `gcloud-python`. It can be quite easily used to handle Django's static and media files. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116653/5043802 and/or issue over at djang-storages: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/491

Answer (score 17):

Django-storages is, in fact, a viable alternative. You must be careful with it's Google Cloud backend though
as the `url()` method it provides causes unnecessary HTTP calls to Google. (Django calls .url() when rendering static files, for example).

https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/491

**settings.py**

```python
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backends.GoogleCloudStaticStorage'
    GS_PROJECT_ID = '<google-cloud-project-id>'
    GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = '<name-of-static-bucket>'
    GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = '<name-of-static-bucket>'
    STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME)
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME)
```

**storage_backends.py**

```python
    """
    GoogleCloudStorage extensions suitable for handing Django's
    Static and Media files.

    Requires following settings:
    MEDIA_URL, GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME
    STATIC_URL, GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME

    In addition to
    https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html
    """
    from django.conf import settings
    from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage
    from storages.utils import setting
    from urllib.parse import urljoin


    class GoogleCloudMediaStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
        """GoogleCloudStorage suitable for Django's Media files."""

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not settings.MEDIA_URL:
                raise Exception('MEDIA_URL has not been configured')
            kwargs['bucket_name'] = setting('GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME', strict=True)
            super(GoogleCloudMediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def url(self, name):
            """.url that doesn't call Google."""
            return urljoin(settings.MEDIA_URL, name)


    class GoogleCloudStaticStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
        """GoogleCloudStorage suitable for Django's Static files"""

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not settings.STATIC_URL:
                raise Exception('STATIC_URL has not been configured')
            kwargs['bucket_name'] = setting('GS_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME', strict=True)
            super(GoogleCloudStaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def url(self, name):
            """.url that doesn't call Google."""
            return urljoin(settings.STATIC_URL, name)
```

Note: authentication is handled by default via the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable

Answer (score 15):

### May, 2022 Update:

With this instruction, you can connect your Django app to your bucket on **GCS(Google Cloud Storage)** and you can serve your static files and serve, upload and delete your media files.

For example, you have **the bucket "my-django-bucket"** on **GCS**:

[image]

And you have **the service account "my-django-bucket-sa"** then you need to copy(Ctrl+C) **the email "my-django-bucket-sa@myproject-347313.iam.gserviceaccount.com"**:

[image]

Next, in **Bucket details** of **the bucket "my-django-bucket"**, click on **"PERMISSIONS"** then **"ADD"**:

[image]

Then, to enable **the service account "my-django-bucket-sa"** to have **the full control of GCS resources**, paste(Ctrl+V) **the email "my-django-bucket-sa@myproject-347313.iam.gserviceaccount.com"** to **"New principals"** then choose **the role "Storage Admin"** then click on **"SAVE"**. *Choose other role by checking [**IAM roles for Cloud Storage**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) if you don't want **the role "Storage Admin" which can have the full control of GCS resources**:

[image]

Next, to enable all users to view(read) files, type **"allUsers"** to **“New principals”** then choose **the role "Storage Legacy Object Reader"** then click on **"SAVE"**:

[image]

Then, you should be asked as shown below so click on **"ALLOW PUBLIC ACCESS"**:

[image]

Finally, you could add **the role "Storage Admin"** to **the service account "my-django-bucket-sa"** and **the role "Storage Legacy Object Reader"** to **"allUsers"**:

[image]

Next, you need to download **the private key of the service account "my-django-bucket-sa" in JSON** so click on **"Manage keys"** from **the 3 dots "⋮"**:

[image]

Then, click on **"Create new key"** from **"ADD KEY"**:

[image]

Then, choose **"JSON"** then click on **"CREATE"**

[image]

Finally, you could download **the private key of the service account "my-django-bucket-sa" in JSON "myproject-347313-020754294843.json"**:

[image]

Now, you have a django project and there are **one settings folder "core"** which has **"static/core/core.js"** and **"settings.py"** and **one application folder "myapp"** which has **"static/myapp/myapp.css"** as shown below:

[image]

Then next, you need to put **"myproject-347313-020754294843.json"** to **the root django project directory where "db.sqlite3" and "manage.py" are**:

[image]

Then, you better rename **"myproject-347313-020754294843.json"** to a shorter and reasonable name such as **"gcpCredentials.json"**:

[image]

Next, you need to install **"django-storages[google]"** to connect to and communicate with **"my-django-bucket"** on **GCS(Google Cloud Storage)**:

```
pip install django-storages[google]
```

By installing **"django-storages[google]"**, you can get **"django-storages"** and **other necessary packages** as shown below:

```
"requirements.txt"

django-storages==1.12.3
cachetools==4.2.4
google-api-core==2.7.2
google-auth==2.6.5
google-cloud-core==2.3.0
google-cloud-storage==2.0.0
google-crc32c==1.3.0
google-resumable-media==2.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.0
protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
```

Be careful, if you install **"django-storages"** without **"[google]"** as shown below:

```
pip install django-storages
```

You can only get **"django-storages"** as shown below.

```
"requirements.txt"

django-storages==1.12.3
```

Next, create **"gcsUtils.py"** in **"core" folder** where **"settings.py"** is:

[image]

Then, put this code below to **"gcsUtils.py"** to define **"Static" and "Media" variables** which each have **a "GoogleCloudStorage" class object**:

```py
# "core/gcsUtils.py"

from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage

Static = lambda: GoogleCloudStorage(location='static')
Media = lambda: GoogleCloudStorage(location='media')
```

Next, add this code below to **"settings.py"**. ***"STATICFILES_STORAGE"** is like the conbination of **"STATIC_ROOT"** and **"STATIC_URL"** and **"DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE"** is like the conbination of **"MEDIA_ROOT"** and **"MEDIA_URL"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Set "static" folder
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'

# Set "media" folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-django-bucket'

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gcpCredentials.json'),
)
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now, **"static" folder** is created in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

And static files are collected from **"admin" and "application" folders** to **"static" folder** in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

And this is **"myapp.css"** in **"myapp" folder**:

[image]

But as you can see, static files are not collected from **the settings folder "core"** to **"static" folder** in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

Because **"STATICFILES_STORAGE"** can only collect static files from **"admin" and "application" folders** but not from other folders like **the settings folder "core"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'
```

So, to collect static files from **the settings folder "core"** to **"static" folder** in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

You need to add **"STATICFILES_DIRS"** to **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]
```

Then, this is **the full code of "settings.py"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]

# Set "static" folder
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'

# Set "media" folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-django-bucket'

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gcpCredentials.json'),
)
```

Then again, run this command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then, static files is collected from **the settings folder "core"** to **"static" folder** in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

And this is **"core.js"** in **"core" folder**:

[image]

Next, this is the code for **"myapp/models.py"**:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/fruits')
    
    def  __str__(self):
        return  str(self.image)
```

And this is the code for **"myapp/admin.py"**:

```py
# "myapp/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image

admin.site.register(Image)
```

Then, upload **"orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Now, **"media" folder** is created in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

And **"orange.jpg"** is uploaded in **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

And because **"GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False"** is set in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
```

If uploading **the same name file "orange.jpg"** again:

[image]

Then, **the unique ID "_VPJxGBW"** is added to **"orange.jpg"**  to prevent **file overwrite** then, **"orange_VPJxGBW.jpg"** is uploaded as shown below:

[image]

Next, if there is **"orange.jpg"** in **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

Then, update(change) **"orange.jpg"** to **"apple.jpg"** being uploaded:

[image]

Then, **"apple.jpg"** is uploaded in **"media/images/fruits"** but **"orange.jpg"** is still in **"media/images/fruits"** without deleted:

[image]

And if there is **"orange.jpg"** in **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

Then, delete **"orange.jpg"**:

[image]

But **"orange.jpg"** is still in **"media/images/fruits"** without deleted:

[image]

So, to delete uploaded files when they are updated(changed) and deleted, you need to install **"django-cleanup"**:

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

Then, add it to the bottom of **"INSTALLED_APPS"** in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig', # Here
)
```

Then, if there is **"orange.jpg"** in **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

Then, update(change) **"orange.jpg"** to **"apple.jpg"** being uploaded:

[image]

Then, **"apple.jpg"** is uploaded in **"media/images/fruits"** and **"orange.jpg"** is deleted from **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

And if there is **"orange.jpg"** in **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

Then, delete **"orange.jpg"**:

[image]

Then, **"orange.jpg"** is deleted from **"media/images/fruits"**:

[image]

Lastly, **the GCS Bucket Settings** which you have just set in **"settings.py"** as shown below work in both **"DEBUG = True"** and **"DEBUG = False"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]

# Set "static" folder
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'

# Set "media" folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-django-bucket'

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gcpCredentials.json'),
)
```

And, there will be **"STATIC_ROOT"**, **"STATIC_URL"**, **"MEDIA_ROOT"**, **"MEDIA_URL"** with **the GCS Bucket Settings** in **"settings.py"** as shown below. So, in this case, **"STATIC_ROOT"**, **"STATIC_URL"**, **"MEDIA_ROOT"** and **"MEDIA_URL"** don't work while **the GCS Bucket Settings** work communicating with **"my-django-bucket"** on **GCS**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from google.oauth2 import service_account

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

'''GCS Bucket Settings Start'''
# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]

# Set "static" folder
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'

# Set "media" folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-django-bucket'

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gcpCredentials.json'),
)
'''GCS Bucket Settings End'''
```

So, if you want **"STATIC_ROOT"**, **"STATIC_URL"**, **"MEDIA_ROOT"** and **"MEDIA_URL"** to work, just comment **the GCS Bucket Settings** then set **"STATICFILES_DIRS"** as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

"""
'''GCS Bucket Settings Start'''
# Collect static files from the settings folder
# "core" which is not "admin" and "application" folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]

# Set "static" folder
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'

# Set "media" folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-django-bucket'

# Add an unique ID to a file name if same file name exists
GS_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gcpCredentials.json'),
)
'''GCS Bucket Settings End'''
"""
```

Answer (score 6):

So, this basically *will* work. (With this library and settings).

The trick to making it work, is knowing where to get the `'user'` and `'key'` parameters for libcloud.

On Google `Cloud Console > Storage`, click `Settings`. Then click on the right-hand tab called `Interoperability`. On that panel, is a lone button, which says something like `Enable Interoperability`. Click it.

***Voila!*** You now have a username and key.

---

**Note:** Do *not* use `django-storages` from pypi. It has not been updated, and doesn't work with recent releases of Django.

Use this version:

`pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages.git#egg=django-storages'`

---

**Edit:** If you want to use a reverse proxy, then you may consider my slightly modified version.
https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/compare/master...halfnibble:master

*Description:*
Under certain circumstances, it may be necessary to load files using a reverse proxy. This could be used to alleviate cross-origin request errors.

This small PR allows the developer to set an optional LIBCLOUD_PROXY_URL in settings.py.

Example Usage

```
# Apache VirtualHost conf
ProxyPass /foo http://storage.googleapis.com
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://storage.googleapis.com


# settings.py
LIBCLOUD_PROXY_URL = '/foo/'
```

Comment: Further note. If you need secured file storage, then I strongly recommend AWS S3 with `django_s3_storage`. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any Google Cloud Storage libraries that support access control for reading files.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the `django-storages` will enable me to use `ImageField` with Google Cloud Storage as the backend. When I want to render the image in the browser (or an app), will I have access to an image url?

Comment: @EvanZamir You are correct. ImageField should work just like FileField when it comes to saving to storage.

Comment: Ok, so I am working with a strict app that only allows https content from the original site. Would I need to use a reverse proxy like this example?

Comment: @ThatCampbellKid You absolutely could use a reverse proxy to achieve that goal. That is often why I use a reverse proxy.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Nostalg.io, definitely good I came across this

Comment: This is old news as of 5/2018. django-storages from pip works fine with Django 2.x and it now has a native backend for Google cloud using `gcloud-python`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116653/5043802.

Answer (score 6):

As the latest version, access key and key ID changed to service account file. And we want to use a bucket with 2 folders `static` and `media` like a local server. Below low the update configs:

Create a file like `gcloud_storages.py`:

```
"""
Modify django-storages for GCloud to set static, media folder in a bucket
"""
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage


class GoogleCloudMediaStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
    """
    GoogleCloudStorage suitable for Django's Media files.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = 'media'
        super(GoogleCloudMediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class GoogleCloudStaticStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
    """
    GoogleCloudStorage suitable for Django's Static files
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = 'static'
        super(GoogleCloudStaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Use `location` argument to set the location of static, media files in bucket*.

In `settings.py`

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
...

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = '/path/service-account.json'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.gcloud_storages.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'app.gcloud_storages.GoogleCloudStaticStorage'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'name-of-bucket'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'project-id'
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'publicRead'
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment on Alan Wagner's answer, here is an addition.

If you are using python3, you may get this error,

```
...
ImportError: No module named 'google_compute_engine'
```

If so, you will need to install google-compute-engine. The `/etc/boto.cfg` file tells python to use the 2.7 version of the library. You will have to run this next line to regenerate `/etc/boto.cfg`.

```
python3 -c "from google_compute_engine.boto.boto_config import BotoConfig; BotoConfig()"
```

Another error you may hit,

```
...
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 95, in create_bucket
    data=get_utf8_value(data))
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 656, in make_request
    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
File "/app/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
    path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3607) to fix this. You may use [my repo](https://github.com/Rsgm/boto) as a pip dependency if you wish until it gets merged.

I will try to keep this repo up to date. I have set the default `develop` branch as protected. I am the only one who can commit/approve merge requests. I have also only made one commit.

You will have to install google-compute-engine and run that line above before you can instalkl/build my boto repo.

Answer (score 1):

I have detailed my step by step process on another thread

- [Serve Static files from Google Cloud Storage Bucket (for Django App hosted on GCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127675/serve-static-files-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket-for-django-app-hosted-on-gc/61519100#61519100)

Here are my main references:

- https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html
- https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05

I used the following packages:

```
pip3 install django-storages # https://pypi.org/project/django-storages/
pip3 install google-cloud-storage # https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/
```