# Can I use apache_libcloud with Django on Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have been having the most difficult time figuring out how to use Google Storage with Django on Google App Engine.

3 days and a thousand searches later, I've arrived at using `django-storages` and `apache-libcloud`.  Everything as I can tell is configured correctly.  My settings mirror [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage).

I've set `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to use my libcloud storage.  But, when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, I get this:

```
Unable to create libcloud driver type libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE: No JSON object could be decoded
```

And when I run `dev_appserver.py .` I get this:

```
Unable to create libcloud driver type libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE: No module named pwd
```

A bit of Googling tells me that `pwd` isn't even allowed on GAE.  So, does that mean `libcloud` and `django-storages` won't work either?  These seam like the best solution for django to use Google Storage, so if they won't work, what will?

AAAH! I'm ready to pour coffee on this laptop.

How far off base am I?  Is it reasonable to expect Google Storage to work with Django on GAE, or should I look elsewhere entirely?

Comment: I have not tried it but it seems this has been answered somewhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage

Comment: I've mentioned to this thread already above.  If it answers my specific question, please explain how.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have read more carefully. I'll try to investigate it and hope you get a good answer soon.