# Google Cloud Storage doesn't upload to the correct media and static directory in the bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created an app in Django and want to use Google Cloud Storage to keep my statics and media files. However, when running `python manage.py collectstatic`

It uploads all the statics to the google cloud bucket root instead of the directory "static" in the bucket.

This is my core/settings/local.py

```
from .base import *  # noqa

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS += ["django_extensions", ]

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"

GS_BUCKET_NAME = "name-bucket"
```

and here is my core/settings/base.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import dj_database_url
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

STATIC_FILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATICFILES_FINDER = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

How can I get to upload my statics to a folder called "static" in my bucket instead in the root? [image]

Comment: Hey, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127675/serve-static-files-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket-for-django-app-hosted-on-gc) thread once. It contains a detailed explanation of what you’re looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **"gcsUtils.py"** in **"core" folder** where **"settings.py" is**:

[image]

Then, put this code below to **"gcsUtils.py"** to define **"Static" and "Media" variables** which each have **a "GoogleCloudStorage" class object**:

```py
# "core/gcsUtils.py"

from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage

Static = lambda: GoogleCloudStorage(location='static')
Media = lambda: GoogleCloudStorage(location='media')
```

Then, replace your code below in **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
```

With this code below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Media'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.gcsUtils.Static'
```

Then, run this command below again:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now, **"static" folder** is created in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

And static files are collected from **"admin" and "application" folders** to **"static" folder** in **"my-django-bucket"**:

[image]

You can see [**the full instruction of Django and GCS bucket**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage/72216226#72216226).

Comment: If you feel one of your answer also answers another question, flag / close the other question as duplicate. Please do not repeating your answers.