# Django creates Static Folder

Tags: django, static

When uploading my statics with `collectstatic' on Google Cloud Storage, it does upload the files into the main root of the bucket, instead in a folder called "/static/", so the web on production can't read the statics. How can I create the folder  "/static/" and upload the files there on GCS?

This are my settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS += ["django_extensions", ]

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"

GS_BUCKET_NAME = "static-bucket"

GS_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket-name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement for loading staticfiles GCS

Go to GCP: Cloud Storage (GCS) and click on CREATE BUCKET (fill-up as needed)

Once created, you can make it public if you want it to act like a CDN of your website (storage of your static files such as css, images, videos, etc.)

Go to your newly created bucket
Go to Permissions and then Click Add members
Add a new member "allUsers" with role "Cloud Storage - Storage Object Viewer"
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-console
Main references:

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html
https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05
Prerequisite steps

Go to GCP: Cloud Storage (GCS) and click on CREATE BUCKET (fill-up as needed)

Once created, you can make it public if you want it to act like a CDN of your website (storage of your static files such as css, images, videos, etc.)

Go to your newly created bucket
Go to Permissions and then Click Add members
Add a new member "allUsers" with role "Cloud Storage - Storage Object Viewer"
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-console

Step one 1 (easier and faster, but requires constant manual copying of files to the GCS)

Configure your Django's static file settings in your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "yourapp1", "templates"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "yourapp2", "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "watever"),
    "/home/me/Music/TaylorSwift/",
    "/home/me/Videos/notNsfw/",
]

STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/mywebsite/"

STATIC_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/<your_bucket_name>/"
```

Step 2 If you have HTML files or CSS files that access other static files, make sure that they reference those other static files with this updated STATIC_URL setting.

In your home.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/home.css' %}">
```

Then in your home.css file

```
background-image: url("../assets/img/myHandsomeImage.jpg");
```

You can actually read the reference from the link i have provided.

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html
https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05

```
You home CSS link now will translate to : 
https://storage.googleapis.com/[your_bucket_name]/home/css/home.css
```

If you wish, you could just put the absolute path (complete URL), but such configuration would always require you to update the used URLs manually, like if you switched to development mode and wanted to just access the static files locally instead of from GCS.
This would copy all files from each directory in STATICFILES_DIRS to STATIC_ROOT directory.

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic

# or if your STATIC_ROOT folder requires permissions to write to it then:
# sudo python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

Okay after searching through stackoverflow i see this problem have been solved and i don't want this to be a form of a duplicate. So here is the link to stackoverflow solution:[Serve Static files from Google Cloud Storage Bucket (for Django App hosted on GCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127675/serve-static-files-from-google-cloud-storage-bucket-for-django-app-hosted-on-gc) .