# Google Cloud Storage with Django getting 403

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, boto, django-storage

Hi I have Django web page and I am migrating to GCloud. I have successfully migrated the DB and now I am trying to migrate the Static and Media storages.

I have this in my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS.append('storages')
GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
GS_BUCKET_NAME = env('GS_BUCKET_NAME')

from storages.backends.gs import GSBotoStorage
StaticGStorage = lambda: GSBotoStorage(location='static')
MediaGStorage = lambda: GSBotoStorage(location='media')

MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/media/'.format(GS_BUCKET_NAME)
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/static/'.format(GS_BUCKET_NAME)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.settings.local.MediaGStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.settings.local.StaticGStorage'
```

I followed this: [Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage#answer-37170899)

In Access key env variables are values from "Interoperability" tab in Settings in GCloud Storage and I am 100% sure that they are loaded correctly. Also the bucket name is correct.
But I am still getting this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 193, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 349, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 255, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 454, in exists
    return k.exists()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 539, in exists
    return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 143, in lookup
    return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/gs/bucket.py", line 111, in get_key
    query_args_l=query_args_l)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 231, in _get_key_internal
    response.status, response.reason, '')
boto.exception.GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Access denied to 'gs://my-bucket-name/static/css/material.grey-orange.min.css'.
```

I get this exception from command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I should probably set something in the GCloud console but I have no idea what is wrong.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can turn on logs and see what request django queries to your server. Thus you can track down why `storages` creates wrong queries.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Idk, I don't know much about `storages` middleware, if there's no logs options you can use 'wireshark' or 'tcpdump' to check requests. The core thing is to see why a request was malformed. By writting raw request you can detect why api is rejecting it.