# Making GCP bucket default storage in Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am not using App Engine.

I have deployed my Django server in my GCP instance and using Django root location for the storage. However, I want to access the GCP bucket and make it as the default storage location for uploading and sending the path to the function used in the views.py

Here's a link [Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage)

From the URL above, I think that the issue can be solved but I'm unable to understand where to deploy the code: **settings.py** or **views.py**?

Is it possible that someone can help me with steps?

Comment: did you find a solution? I am using app engine but having similar issue