# How can I use Google cloud Storage with django-storages

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I'm **not** using App Engine.
I read this page. [Configure Django and Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage/50116653#50116653) I installed django-storages and boto. I set my setting file like this.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = '***'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gs.GSBotoStorage'
```

Then I run this code

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
default_storage.exists('storage_test')
```

Then I got this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GSResponseError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8a49776d7c1d> in <module>()
      1 from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
----> 2 default_storage.exists('storage_test')

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py in exists(self, name)
    433                 return False
    434 
--> 435         return self._get_key(name) is not None
    436 
    437     def listdir(self, name):

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py in _get_key(self, name)
    419         if self.entries:
    420             return self.entries.get(name)
--> 421         return self.bucket.get_key(self._encode_name(name))
    422 
    423     def delete(self, name):

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/gs/bucket.py in get_key(self, key_name, headers, version_id, response_headers, generation)
    109         try:
    110             key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers,
--> 111                                                query_args_l=query_args_l)
    112         except GSResponseError as e:
    113             if e.status == 403 and 'Forbidden' in e.reason:

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py in _get_key_internal(self, key_name, headers, query_args_l)
    230             else:
    231                 raise self.connection.provider.storage_response_error(
--> 232                     response.status, response.reason, '')
    233 
    234     def list(self, prefix='', delimiter='', marker='', headers=None,

GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Access denied to 'gs://***/storage_test'.
```

How can I solve this problem.please help me!

This is document of [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html)

Comment: Did you set up the environment variable called: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS? You should be able to download it (a .json file) from your gcloud console.  See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable.

Comment: Oh! I didn't set it. Thank you! It's works now!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set up the environment variable called: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. You should be able to download it (a .json file) from your gcloud console.

See [documention](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable) for more details.