# How to restrict access to only service account users in google cloud storage permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to give permissions for google cloud storage buckets with service account json file using django-storages.But the items in buckets are getting accessible only when i gave  access to allUsers with Objects View Permission.How can i restrict public access for the bucket.

Comment: * Service Account User..

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this [link](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) that contains a useful guide about the process required to connect Django to GCS by using [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) JSON files; in this way, you can implement this authentication method to access to your buckets instead of [making your data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). Adittionally, please keep in mind it is required to assign the [Cloud Storage IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to the service account, by using the [IAM console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#using_iam_with_buckets) or   by creating [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#set-an-acl), in order to grant the access permissions.

Finally, once you have your Service account key file ready, you can authenticate your application by setting the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** environment variable with the path of the json file or passing the path directly into your code, as explained in the [GCS official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'll try.

Comment: I tried the same method as you mentioned, images are still showing access denied error.

Comment: This issue is commonly related to the way that the JSON auth files are passed to the application. I recommend you to verify that your credentials file is being read correctly. Additionally, I suggest you to take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage/50116653#50116653), which contains some advises about the process required to connect `django-storages` to `GCS` by using `Interoperability` keys that may be helpful for your solution.

Comment: What is the benefit of setting up a service account to access GCS objects versus using public URLs?