# How should a web application ensure security when serving confidential media files?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, media

**Question:** Say a user uploads highly confidential information. This is placed in a third party storage server. This third party bucket uses different authentication systems to the web application. What is the best practice for ensuring only the user or an admin staff member can access the file url?

**More Context:** A Django web application is running on Google App Engine Flexible. Google Storage is used to serve static and media files through Django. The highly confidential information is passports, legal contracts etc.

**Static files** are served in a fairly insecure way. The `/static/` bucket is public, and files are served through django's static files system. This works because

- there is no confidential or user information in any of our static
  files, only stock images, css and javascript, and
- the files are uglified and minifed before production.

For **media files** however, we need user specific permissions, if user A uploads an image, then user A can view it, staff can view it, but user B & unauthenticated users cannot under any circumstances view it. This includes if they have the url.

My preferred system would be, that GCP storage could use the same django authentication server, and so when a browser requested `...google.storage..../media/user_1/verification/passport.png`, we could check what permissions this user had, compare it against the uploaded user ID, and decide whether to show a 403 or the actual file.

What is the industry standard / best practice solution for this issue?

Do I make both buckets only accessible to the application, using a service account, and ensure internally that the links are only shared if the correct user is viewing the page? (anyone for static, and {user or staff} for media?)

**My questions, specifically** (regarding web application security):

1. Is it safe to serve static files from a publicly readable bucket?
2. Is it okay to assume that if my application requests a file url, that this is from an authenticated user?
3. Specifically with regards to Django & GCP Storage, if 2 is false (I believe it is) how do I ensure that files served from buckets are
   only visible to users with the correct permissions?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and it sounds like you're asking for folks' opinions. Could you narrow it down to a specific ask that can be answered more-or-less objectively?

Comment: I was hoping the use of context after the broad question would lower the scope. I will try to edit it to lower the scope.

Comment: Is your `GCP Storage` accessible directly via URL or do you have control over it - meaning it is just the storage behind your proxy? We are using X-Accel for delivering Django's /media content from nginx, stored in our case on Azure storage. If this is what you are looking for, I can add an answer. See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it is. [Public readable buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) are made for that. Things like, CSS, the logo of you company or some files that have no sensible data are safe to share.

***Of course, do not use the same Public bucket to store private/public stuff. Public with Public, Private with Private.***

---

2. Here is the problem. When you say "authenticated user", to whom you want that user to be authenticated to?

For example, if you authenticate your user using any [Django methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/), then the user will be authenticated to Django, but for Cloud Storage it will be an stranger. Also, even a user authorized on GCP may not be authorized to a bucket on Cloud Storage.

The important thing here is that the one that communicates back and forth with Cloud Storage is not the User, its Django. It could achieve this by using the [python SDK of Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python), which takes the **credentials of the service account** that is being used on the instance to authenticate any request to Cloud Storage. So, the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/service-account) that is running the VM (because you are in Flexible) is the one that should be authorized to Cloud Storage.

---

3. You must first authorize the user on Django and then check if the User is able to access this file by other means(Like storing the name of the file he uploaded in a user_uploaded_files table).

---

Regarding your first question at the top of the post, Cloud Storage lets you create [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). This urls allow anyone on the internet to upload/download files from Cloud Storage by just holding the url. So you only need to authorize the user on Django to obtain the signed url and that's it. He does not need to be "authorized" on Cloud Storage(because the url already does it)

Taken from the docs linked before:

> When should you use a signed URL?
>
> In some scenarios, you might not
>   want to require your users to have a Google account in order to access
>   Cloud Storage, but you still want to control access using your
>   application-specific logic. The typical way to address this use case
>   is to provide a signed URL to a user, which gives the user read,
>   write, or delete access to that resource for a limited time. Anyone
>   who knows the URL can access the resource until the URL expires. You
>   specify the expiration time in the query string to be signed.

Comment: Thank you! This is the perfect answer. I have been working all day on a solution and have just come to the same conclusion. I was about to answer this myself when I came across your answer.

I'll post an answer anyway with details about my implementation for interest.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Nahuel Varela's answer:

My system now consists of 4 buckets:

- static
- media
- static-staging
- media-staging

Both the static buckets are public, and the media buckets are only accessible to the **app engine service account** created within the project. 
(The settings are different for dev / test)

I'm using the `django-storages[google]`with [@elnygrens modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116653/7874822). I modified this to remove the `url` method for Media (so that we create signed URLS) but keep it in for static (so that we access the public URL of the static files).

The authentication of each file access is done in Django, and if the user passes the test (is_staff or id matches file id), then they're given access to the file for a given amount of time (currently 1 hour), this access refreshes when the page loads etc.

Follow up question: What is the best practice for this time limit, I've heard people use anywhere from 15mins to 24 hours?

Comment: I have seen you have posted a question inside the answer, I recommend you to open a new SO post referencing this one to ask that question so you could receive proper attention. Still, I believe that it will depend on each use case, but one hour seems fine to me.