# Django 2: upload media to Google Cloud Storage with google-cloud-storage

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage

I want to deploy Django app on Google Cloud (Google AppEngine and Cloud Sql). SO I need to store media files in Google CLoud Storage.

I found this code in google docs:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
# https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[bucket-id]/
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id-here')
# Then do other things...
blob = bucket.get_blob('remote/path/to/file.txt')
print(blob.download_as_string())
blob.upload_from_string('New contents!')
blob2 = bucket.blob('remote/path/storage.txt')
blob2.upload_from_filename(filename='/local/path.txt')
```

I think I can use this in the views (for a FileField and an ImageField). But what should I do in my Django settings with MEDIA_ROOT in this case?

Comment: You may find https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html very helpful here

Comment: is it possible to do it without django-storages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in this way:

views.py

```
from google.cloud import storage

def your_view(self, request):
    #some your code
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(settings.GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
    #path to the cloud storage "directory"
    prefix = 'media/'
    delimiter = '/'
    blobs = client.list_blobs(
        bucket,
        prefix = prefix,
        delimiter = delimiter
    )
    blob = storage.blob.Blob(
        name = name,
        bucket = bucket)
    blob.upload_from_string(
        resized_image, #some data
        content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    )
    # other your code
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/YOUR_BUCKET/media/'
GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = 'YOUR_BUCKET'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look into [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage). Also whats comments @Oluwafemi Sule is true. On the other hand [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample) you can find an example with python.
Maybe you want to do some examples to clarify the usage, just have in mind that as [this](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) is a third party tool,Google cannot vouch for its accuracy.