# google Engine ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage, django-storage

I´m receiving this error where I deploy my app on Google Engine. When I run it locally it works. I already have that dependency in my requirements file.
I checked the logs on google console and it show that in the build it installed django-storages.

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process      super().init_process()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process      self.load_wsgi()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi      self.callable = self.load()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load      return self.load_wsgiapp()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app      mod = importlib.import_module(module)    
File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module    
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed    
File "/srv/main.py", line 1, in <module>      from app_admin.wsgi import application    
File "/srv/app_admin/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>      application = get_wsgi_application()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application      django.setup(set_prefix=False)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate      app_config.import_models()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models      self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)    
File "/opt/python3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    
File "/srv/upload/models.py", line 2, in <module>      from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'
```

models.py

```
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage

storage = GoogleCloudStorage()


class Upload:

    @staticmethod
    def upload_image(file, filename):
        try:
            target_path = filename
            path = storage.save(target_path, file)
            return storage.url(path)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to upload!")
            message = traceback.format_exc()
            print(message)
```

Comment: are you installing `django-storages[google]` or just `django-storages`? make sure you are installing the proper `django-storages[google]`

Comment: I run the command ```pip install django-storages[google]``` but in requirements files this dependency appear ```django-storages==1.12.3```

Comment: does your `requirements.txt` have `google-cloud-storage==2.0.0` in it?

Comment: yeah, it has ```google-cloud-storage==2.3.0```

Comment: i would maybe take a look at the **May 2022 update** answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247702/configure-django-and-google-cloud-storage), it seems very detailed.

Comment: Thanks @JackWotherspoon , I was missing some variables in my settings file. The thread you shared me was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

did you install the module in your virtual environment or on server? Also, check versions of pip while installing and python version which running Django process. Try using python3 manage.py run server